# Equivalent SVG transform for new coordinate system

Tags: javascript, svg, transform, coordinate-systems, affinetransform

SVG is embedded in an object tag which has some dimensions (w1,h1). The user can zoom and pan to an arbitrary region in the SVG and wants to retain that view.
I have the transform of the SVG with old dimensions. How to compute the transformation for the SVG to retain the previous view for the new dimensions(w2, h2)?
Here is an example HTML, the SVG is embedded in the object tag
In this example, (w1,h1) are (100%,100%) and (w2,h2) can be (50% ,50%)

```
<html>
<body>
<object class="auto-capital-svg-content" data="1.svg" width="100%" height="100%" type="image/svg+xml">
</object>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is a sample SVG

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xml:space="preserve" height="150" width="400" style="" >
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="grad1" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="0%">
      <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,255,0);stop-opacity:1"></stop>
      <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,0,0);stop-opacity:1"></stop>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <g id="viewport" transform="matrix(6,0,0,6,200,200)">
  <ellipse cx="200" cy="70" rx="85" ry="55" fill="url(#grad1)"></ellipse>
  <text fill="#ffffff" font-size="45" font-family="Verdana" x="150" y="86">SVG</text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

This is what I thought : calculate the scale based on the new/old dimensions such that aspect ratio is preserved and scale the transform. But this did not take care of the translation (tx,ty) in the matrix {a,b,c,d,tx,ty}.What should be done here?

Comment: Please create a [mcve] and add it to the question.

Comment: @RobertLongson added an example ,Thanks.